# trouble with basic numpy multiplication

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

In my code, I multiply two matrices:

```
c = b*a
```

Where `a` outputs as

```
array([array([-0.08358731,  0.07145386,  0.1052811 , -0.05362566]),
       array([-0.05335939, -0.03136824, -0.01260714,  0.11532605]),
       array([-0.09164538,  0.02280118, -0.00290509,  0.09415849])], dtype=object)
```

and `b` outputs as

```
array([ 0.60660017,  0.54703557,  0.69928535,  0.70157223])
```

...That should work right (where values of b is multiplied by each value of each row in a)?

Instead, I get

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3) (4)

But then when I try it in a separate python console, it works great.
(bare in mind I've set `array = np.array`)

```
>>>  aa = array([array([-0.12799382,  0.07758469, -0.02968546, -0.01811048]),
               array([-0.00465869, -0.00483031, -0.00591955, -0.00386022]),
               array([-0.02036786,  0.0078658 ,  0.09493727, -0.01790333])], dtype=object)

>>> bb = array([ 0.16650179,  0.74140229,  0.60859776,  0.37505098])

>>> aa * bb
array([[-0.021311200138937801, 0.057521466834940096, -0.0180665044605696,
        -0.0067923532722703999],
       [-0.00077568022405510005, -0.0035812028954099002,
        -0.0036026248702079999, -0.0014477792940156],
       [-0.0033912851484694004, 0.0058317221326819992, 0.0577786098625152,
        -0.0067146614617633995]], dtype=object)
```

The fact it works here really confuses me...

Comment: when you say `matrices` do you mean you are using `numpy.matrix` in your code? multiplication for matrix objects don't follow elementwise operations.

Comment: sorry - just mean arrays

Comment: then what does `a.shape()` print out? if it is just `(3,)` that would be the issue, a isn't registered as a proper 2D array

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen It's clearly not just from OP's output. It's an array of arrays.

Comment: @harrylakins. Why `aa = array([array([-0.12799382,  0.07758469, -0.02968546, -0.01811048]),
           array([-0.00465869, -0.00483031, -0.00591955, -0.00386022]),
           array([-0.02036786,  0.0078658 ,  0.09493727, -0.01790333])], dtype=object)` instead of just `aa = array([[-0.12799382,  0.07758469, -0.02968546, -0.01811048],
           [-0.00465869, -0.00483031, -0.00591955, -0.00386022],
           [-0.02036786,  0.0078658 ,  0.09493727, -0.01790333]])`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist you can't end up with a single dimensional array of array objects from a literal because numpy will recognize this and compensate, however it can be done (by accident usually) as [MSeifert's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41106653/5827215) demonstrates.  I think the literal expression is just the output instead of the actual statement used to create `aa`.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen. Agreed, but the first part of the question clearly states `Where a outputs as ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first array has only 1 dimension and 3 "object" elements while your second array has 1 dimension and 4 float elements. [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) uses element-wise arithmetic operations and there is just no way it can do that with one 3-item array and a 4-item array therefore the Exception.

```
>>> x = np.empty(3, dtype=object)
>>> x[0] = np.array([-0.08358731,  0.07145386,  0.1052811 , -0.05362566])
>>> x[1] = np.array([-0.05335939, -0.03136824, -0.01260714,  0.11532605])
>>> x[2] = np.array([-0.09164538,  0.02280118, -0.00290509,  0.09415849])
>>> x.shape
(3, )
```

<sub>The example above is an awful way of creating a `numpy.array` and should be avoided!</sub>

The difference to your second example is that it doesn't have numpy-arrays inside an array, it creates a multidimensional (3x4) array:

```
>>> x_new = np.array(list(x))
>>> x_new  # no nested arrays!
array([[-0.12799382, 0.07758469, -0.02968546, -0.01811048],
       [-0.00465869, -0.00483031, -0.00591955, -0.00386022],
       [-0.02036786, 0.0078658, 0.09493727, -0.01790333]], dtype=object)
>>> x_new.shape
(3, 4)
```

That the multiplication operation works with the new array (`x_new` or your `aa`) is because numpy broadcasts the arrays. Here every row will be multiplied by one of your items in the second array.

Comment: i understand - cheers. What do you suggest i do in order to multiply each row of a by b to result in the same shape as a?

Comment: @harrylakins. Don't declare `a` as a weird abomination and the problem will take care of itself. See my comment about how I would expect you to declare it.

Comment: @harrylakins Actually numpy-broadcasting should do that by default (at least if I understand your "multiply each row of a by b" correctly). You should probaby try to create a multidimensional array of integer or floating dtype (always try to avoid object) in the first place.

Comment: If `b` matches `a` in shape and type, then `a*b` works - see my latest edit.

Comment: @hpaulj You're correct but that's not really appropriate for floats (if one uses numpy). Better to add a custom dimension (`np.expand_dims()` or with `np.newaxis`) than to have nested arrays, right?

Comment: Something else, probably not the OP's own code, has created that array of arrays, using the kind of trick that you and I demonstrate.  I agree that converting it to a 2d array is best.  But `harry` did ask about working directly with `a`.  We'd have to go that direction is the subarrays of `a` differed in shape.

Comment: ok, I assumed it wasn't just a coincidence that `a` had 4 columns and `b` contained 4 elements. The OP stated that `aa * bb` solved his problem and he wanted to know why it didn't work with `a * b`.

Answer (score 2):

Your original `a` and the copy `aa` have different shapes.  Do a `a.shape` and `aa.shape`.  The problem is with how object arrays are created.  `np.array` tries to create as high a dimensional object as it can.

`a` is (3,) array, a 1d array containing 3 arrays.

`aa` is (3,4) array, a 2d array contain numbers as objects (not floats).

To construct `a` I have to take a convoluted route:

```
In [659]: a=np.empty((3,), object)
In [660]: a[0]=np.array([-0.08358731,  0.07145386,  0.1052811 , -0.05362566])
     ...: a[1]=np.array([-0.05335939, -0.03136824, -0.01260714,  0.11532605])
     ...: a[2]=np.array([-0.09164538,  0.02280118, -0.00290509,  0.09415849])
     ...: 
In [661]: a
Out[661]: 
array([array([-0.08358731,  0.07145386,  0.1052811 , -0.05362566]),
       array([-0.05335939, -0.03136824, -0.01260714,  0.11532605]),
       array([-0.09164538,  0.02280118, -0.00290509,  0.09415849])], dtype=object)
In [662]: a.shape
Out[662]: (3,)
```

I can multiply those 3 elements with another 3 element array (that doesn't always work with `object` arrays, but here the elements implement `*`.)

```
In [663]: a*np.array([0,1,2])
Out[663]: 
array([array([-0.,  0.,  0., -0.]),
       array([-0.05335939, -0.03136824, -0.01260714,  0.11532605]),
       array([-0.18329076,  0.04560236, -0.00581018,  0.18831698])], dtype=object)
```

But if I copy-n-paste as you did I get

```
In [665]: aa = array([array([-0.12799382,  0.07758469, -0.02968546, -0.01811048]
     ...: ),
     ...:            array([-0.00465869, -0.00483031, -0.00591955, -0.00386022])
     ...: ,
     ...:            array([-0.02036786,  0.0078658 ,  0.09493727, -0.01790333])
     ...: ], dtype=object)
In [666]: aa.shape
Out[666]: (3, 4)
```

Now that (3,4) can multiply a (4,) array.

`vstack` can convert the (3,) object array into a (3,4) array of floats:

```
In [667]: a3=np.vstack(a)
In [668]: a3.shape
Out[668]: (3, 4)
In [669]: a3.dtype
Out[669]: dtype('float64')
In [670]: a3
Out[670]: 
array([[-0.08358731,  0.07145386,  0.1052811 , -0.05362566],
       [-0.05335939, -0.03136824, -0.01260714,  0.11532605],
       [-0.09164538,  0.02280118, -0.00290509,  0.09415849]])
```

==============

You can multiply `a` by a `b` that matches it in shape and type:

```
In [681]: b=np.empty((3,),object)
In [682]: for i in range(3):
     ...:     b[i]=np.arange(i,i+4)
     ...:     
In [683]: b    # 3 arrays of length 4 each
Out[683]: array([array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([2, 3, 4, 5])], dtype=object)
In [684]: a*b
Out[684]: 
array([array([-0.        ,  0.07145386,  0.2105622 , -0.16087698]),
       array([-0.05335939, -0.06273648, -0.03782142,  0.4613042 ]),
       array([-0.18329076,  0.06840354, -0.01162036,  0.47079245])], dtype=object)
```

Basically it is doing: `for i in range(3): res[i]=a[i]*b[i]`